# NuGet References invalid when changed to Release build configuration

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget

I'm experiencing rather a strange issue with NuGet (most recent) and VS2012. I have a multi-project solution with NuGet package management enabled and as long as I'm using Debug|AnyCPU configuration, it all compiles and application runs correctly. As soon as I switch to Release|AnyCPU, it seems like all the NuGet assembly references were gone and the app obviously do not compile. Strangely, I can see all the references in NuGet Manager UI for all the correct projects.

Did you ever experienced similar issue and do you know how to fix it?

Rebuild did not helped. NuGet references were set up while Debug configuration was set.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once again, I'm answering my own question...

The point was, I was changing the structure of solution and moved some projects around. That means, you get invalid *relative* paths in .csproj files per project. Which is OK, as long as you don't change the depth of the structure, which I did.

For **unknown reason**, debug build went just fine with invalid paths (probably the assemblies are gathered some other way, as I manually deleted bin and obj folders and cleared solution, etc...). But for release build, it tried to obtain the assemblies from the (wrongly referenced) packages/ directory.

NO PART of NuGet process found/reported this issue and in all UI consoles and even in the NuGet PowerShell Console itself, everything seemed just OK.

The solution is obvious. Edit the .csproj files for affected projects (I was actually guided to the issue by filtering warnings and finding out, only some assemblies were affected and those were from outside of the main solution directory) and change the paths of assembly references to correct NuGet packages folder.

*On the side note:* This is THE problem of NuGet (and possibly VS) references handling. It is trying to use some relative paths instead of adding some variable like ${SOLUTION_ROOT} or ${NUGET_ROOT} or ${PACKAGES_FOLDER}. If it was done by variable replacement, one could use the same projects in multiple solutions, without breaking NuGet packages configuration. At least I haven't found the way to share the same project folder across multiple solutions.

Comment: I had the same issue, but was caused by a merge of the .csproj file. I had to unload/edit the project and remove the duplicate references so that NuGet could managed them again after reloading the project file in the solution.

Comment: I hit the same.  I think the reason debug still worked is because the DLLs were in the BIN directory from previous builds; so could be reused; whilst the Release build was the first since I'd moved my project / broken the relative paths as you describe.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to resolve this issue by uninstalling, then installing the Nuget packages my project was using.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but it may help someone. This issue can occur if you change your nuget `repositoryPath` (perhaps via nuget.config), to a different path, mid project.

e.g.

- Nuget will initially pull your packages into a default path
- Nuget repositoryPath is changed.
- New packages will be pulled into this path, however the existing path will not be cleared down (msbuild clean wont help either).
- When you build, your hint paths, will point to the initial repo path, and will build, as the packages still exist in that location.
- (Worse) Any nuget packages added now, will point to the new repo path.

As mentioned by @Baron, reinstalling will resolve all this mess. I'd also recommend deleting all bin/obj/packages from your working tree, to ensure you don't have any crud.